# How to make the panel which stick on the tube faded(color faded) randomly in blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, color

This is the material that I try to make. At first I use Quixel Mixer to draw my texture, then import to blender. But I can't get the same result with the reference.

How to make the panel which stick on the tube faded randomly?

And why my texture looks pinker in blender?

[image: This is a image from https://www.behance.net/gallery/85433519/Berlin-Architecture]

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: is your texture supposed to be clean/uniform or a bit dirty/heterogeneous? Also, about the panels, you could either make 3D panels or draw them in the image texture

Comment: Could you please edit your question and use a descriptive title?

Comment: @moonboots Which I made in Quixel Mixer was a clean one but it looks pinker in blender. You mean if I want to make the panels faded, I just create the faded one to stick on the tube. Because if I draw the faded panels in the texture. The faded panels will keep appear on the tube seems like they are "array".  By the way, thanks for your comments :))

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I edited it. Thanks:)